# IBM Installation Manager openSUSE

Tags: websphere, opensuse, ibm-installation-manager

I am trying to install the IBM Installation Manager under openSUSE.
When I run it from the command line I get the following error:

```
./install --launcher.ini silent-install.ini -acceptLicense 

ERROR: Exception caught while evaluating expression in bundle "com.ibm.cic.agent.oac".

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "42.1"

java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:77)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:539)
com.ibm.cic.agent.oac.AbstractIMOAC.isSLES(AbstractIMOAC.java:342)
com.ibm.cic.agent.oac.AbstractIMOAC.checkForEndOfLife(AbstractIMOAC.java:144)
com.ibm.cic.agent.oac.AbstractIMOAC.doOAC(AbstractIMOAC.java:99)
com.ibm.cic.agent.oac.AbstractIMOAC.evaluate(AbstractIMOAC.java:83)
com.ibm.cic.agent.oac.IMOAC.evaluate(IMOAC.java:45)
```

So apparently the IM thinks this is SLES and doesn't recognise version number "42.1".

I found a very similar error report
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI55180

> Adding "im.suppress.unsupported.platform.check=true" to the
>   "config.ini" file located in \configuration
>   directory of the extracted IM installation repository will suppress
>   the Supported platform check.

I made this change, but the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the IBM Technote that you have linked to, the above problem affects Installation Manager v1.8.4, and a fix is available with v1.8.5.

However, according to the [SPCR](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1407280189309&osPlatforms=Linux#) for IM 1.8.5, **openSUSE is not listed as a supported platform**. SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 10/11 & SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 10/11/12 are listed.

You will need to use a supported platform for installing IM and any related IBM products.

Comment: The fix refers to SUSE Linux 12.1 being included to the supported platforms. I was just wondering why the configuration option doesn't work, if there is another way to bypass this check.

Comment: The APAR refers to SUSE 12.1, which is different from openSUSE Leap 42.1. Perhaps the installer will simply not install to an unsupported platform? You can try installing IM v1.8.5 as an alternative, which is the recommended action according to the APAR.

Comment: It is recommended for installing SUSE 12.1, not openSUSE.